# ability to add event location to FullCalendarIO

Tags: fullcalendar

What to know if it is possible to add locations to events in the fullcalendar.io. as nothing in the demo for meeting locations or in documentation?

Answer (score 1):

The document of [Event Object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) mentions that you can include your own fields in the Event Object. FullCalendar will not modify or delete them but also won't render them.

So you can add locations to your events, but you have to find your own way to render them.

You can find the document of eventRender [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender).

And here is an example for showing the event location:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    defaultDate: '2018-10-07',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: [{
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: '2018-10-12T14:30:00',
      location: 'Conference Room'
    }],
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.text(element.text() + ' ' + event.location)

    }
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add fields that aren't included in what FullCalendar will render you can check the doc https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventRender first of all.

In my case I've done this using the eventRender function to add the location after the already existing text, ofc you need to add the additional fields to the extendedProps:

```html
eventRender: function(info) {
            info.el.innerText = info.el.outerText + ' ' + info.event._def.extendedProps.location;
        }
```